# Delaying a jQuery .click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok so I have a little issue here,

```
    $("#WhoAreWe").click(function(){
    $("#Image").hide();
    $("#Two").slideUp(1000);
    $("#Third").slideUp(1000);
    $("#Fourth").slideUp(1000);
    $("#WhoAreWe").hide();
    $("#WhoAreWe2").slideToggle(3000);
    $("#IDs").slideDown(3000);

        $("#main").click(function(){
    alert("Pressed Back");
});
```

(The alert is just a place holder)

Basically the #main is the entire page, and when any point on the site is pressed. It works fine but the problem is that when I first press #WhoAreWe it also runs the $("#main") function. My problem is that whenever WhoAreWe is pressed, main also runs. I don't want this, I just want it to run when the user clicks anywhere on the page AFTER clicking on WhoAreWe.

Edit:

Just to make it clear, #WhoAreWe is a Div (Text).

## main is the ENTIRE PAGE

Comment: do i get this right, your main question is: how can you bind a click to `#main` after clicking `#WhoAreWe` ?

Comment: It's just that I want #main to be enabled only once after WhoAreWe is clicked. And when WhoAreWe is NOT clicked I do not want #main to be possible to click.

Comment: ok then i have the right answer :) you could also toggle it like turing it of and on :)

Comment: coould you pleade post your html ? at least a snipit of it

Comment: I added my HTML page, I didn't include the CSS files and most of the jQuery code.

Comment: i have added 2 more fiddles, guess the last one is the one you looking for.

Comment: didnt meant like this... create a fiddle sample of your ENTIRE PAGE just with a sample on it. as i sayed, in my post is a working fiddle allready. see "div-fiddle waiting"

Comment: Not sure why, but none of what was posted is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this example:

**script**

```
$(function(){
    $("#main").on('click', function(e) {
        if($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
            return;
        }
        alert('Its main ....');
    });
    $("#whoAreWe").on('click', function(e) {
        alert('Its Who Are We ....');
        $("#main").removeClass('disabled');
    });
});
```

**html**

```
<input type="button" value="Who are we ?" id="whoAreWe" />
<input type="button" value="Main" id="main" class="disabled"/>
```

***EDIT***

**script**

```
$(function () {
    $("#main").on('click', function (e) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
            return;
        }
        alert('Its main ....');
    });
    $("#whoAreWe").on('click', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $("#main").removeClass('disabled');
        alert('Its Who Are We ....');
    });
});
```

**html**

```
<div id="main" class="disabled">
    <div id="whoAreWe">Who Are We ?</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Main is not a button, but the Entire Page. The fiddles are correct, but instead of having main as a button, I want main to be the ENTIRE PAGE.

Comment: @user3890432, it would be great if you can post a fiddle, so that we can help you better.

Comment: I added my HTML code above if you can take a look (:

Comment: @user3890432, kindly check my updated post. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j1tz0y6o/)

Comment: Still no success even with the edit, I can press anything on the page BEFORE pressing WhoAreWe.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60283/discussion-between-arvind-and-user3890432).

Answer (score 0):

Updated: Previously the "clicked" variable wasn't defined globally... now I've changed it to a global variable...

```
$(document).ready(function (){

var window.clicked=false;

$("#WhoAreWe").click(function(){
    $("#Image").hide();
    $("#Two").slideUp(1000);
    $("#Third").slideUp(1000);
    $("#Fourth").slideUp(1000);
    $("#WhoAreWe").hide();
    $("#WhoAreWe2").slideToggle(3000);
    $("#IDs").slideDown(3000);

    window.clicked=true;    

});



$("#main").click(function(){
    if(!window.clicked){
        alert("Pressed Back");
    }
});


});
```

Comment: Looks like that's not working for me either, alert is never ran.

Comment: Still won't work, in fact. Implementing that code seems to have completely messed up my site.

Answer (score 0):

guess this should work fine too

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#whoAreWe').on('click', function(){

        $(':not(#whoAreWe)').on('click', function(){
            $('#main').unbind('click').on('click', function(){
                //unbind and bin click to prevent multi bindings
                alert('Pressed Back');
            });
        });
    }); 
});
```

and take care you have it wrapped in `$(document).ready();`. You should put all you actions in there.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vxkn0s8o/)**

**[DIV-FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vxkn0s8o/2/)**

**[DIV-FIDDLE waiting](http://jsfiddle.net/vxkn0s8o/4/)**

**[FIDDLE WITH YOUR HTML AS SAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vxkn0s8o/5/)**

Comment: #WhoAreWe And #main are text. Also, what I mean is that once #WhoAreWe is press anywhere on the page (There is no "Main" button, "Main" is the entire page)

Comment: so what are they ? divs / tables / eggs / chicken / dogs ? :D

Comment: Yes, they are divs (: (main === ENTIRE WEBPAGE)

Comment: @user3890432 see my changes